# Клонирование RAID1 массива

Tags: raid

Привет всем!

Поделитесь опытом клонирования RAID1 массива.

Есть аппаратный RAID1 массив на нем ОС, можно ли перенести на программный RAID1 массив.

Можно ли перенести систему не приостанавливая работу сервера и как?

Comment: "не приостанавливая работу сервера" - зачем?я к тому, что приостановить сервер придётся, а что за сервис? может проще перенести его, а не весь сервер байт-в-байт

Comment: На серваке стоит 1с сама база на другом RAID'e. Поэтому хотелось бы перенести ОС без остановки сервака.

Comment: Простите, но как это можно? РАБОТАЮЩУЮ!!! Базу надо резервировать, а проги восстановить - как два пальца! А конфиги - вообще дома у себя держать надо!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаете образ вашего блочного устройства, т.е. ваш аппаратный RAID1 массив, далее разворачиваете его на программном блочном устройстве. Profit?! Только вопрос в том как на это отреагирует ваша ОС?! И да, делать это онлайн лучше не надо.

Comment: Попробуем сегодня спасибо!

Comment: Создал образ аппаратного RAID1 при восстановление пишет: "Вы собираетесь восстановить системный том на динамический диск. Это может привести к невозможности загрузить систему после восстановления."

Comment: Жми далее...

Answer (score 1):

В образ: dd if=/dev/md127 of=/имя_образа.img

Загрузочная запись:dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1 count=512

Но лично я бы воспользовался для съема образа дистром Clonzilla и в нормальных условиях, т.е. на заглушенной системе.

Кстати, утилита dd может лить образ по сети... Да, и при создании образа с работающей системы, не удасться создать ее точную копию, т.к. изменения будут происходить каждую долю секунды. В том числе и при init 3...

Желаю успехов!

Comment: Спасибо за Clonzilla, полезная вещь. И непонятно про dd это утилита для Unix же? У меня MS Windows Server 2008.

Comment: конечно! dd - это unix. Рад что Вам приглянулась Clonzilla, не раз меня выручала. Особенно радует скорость и стабильность работы.

Comment: Чтобы никто ничего неправильно не понял - поясню! Утилита dd в никсах - это утилита копирования файлов. Изначально. И не более того! Но, поскольку, любое подключённое устройство в никсах отображается на файловое пространство, и является файлом, то возникает возможность работы с этим устройством как с обычным файлом. Виндузятники, как правило, этого просто не понимают, и восстанавливать после них мне уже давно надоело! Поэтому прошу: если не знаете - не делайте!!!

Answer (score 0):

Можно (но я бы не стал - стремно). Ну и перезагружаться пару раз все равно придется:

1. Сделать бекапы
2. Сделать бекапы!
3. Проверить бекапы.
4. Разломать аппаратный рейд - убрать из него один диск, оставить raid1 из одного диска.
5. Второй диск добавить в систему как другой raid1 из одного диска либо как отдельный диск (зависит от контроллера).
6. woodo-магия: добавить первый уже существующий диск в raid. В Linux для этого надо лезть в суперблок и что-то там писать. В Windows - хз, может вообще нельзя. Самый стремный момент.
7. Добавить второй диск в новый software raid.
8. Profit?

Comment: Не Profit.Из одно диска нельзя RAID1 создать, контроллеру нужно два диска одинакового объема и он их форматирует, так что не вариант.